# Application appearing on all spaces in Lion

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

I had a couple of applications set up to be on all spaces when I was running on Snow Leopard, but now that I'm on Lion I want to turn that off.

I can't work out how to do it. Does anyone know how? There doesn't seem to be an option in System Preferences for it. Perhaps there's a plist or something similar I can edit?

Comment: I was going to ask a similar question, but I am too late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the dock you can right click the application, go to Options and de-select the option there.

[image]

Comment: Picture worth many words - nice! :-)

Answer (score 2):

When the app is running, you can hold your mouse pressed over the dock icon and change desktop binding to none or a specific space. A secondary click works too.